# Oracle find record if the given date is within the range

Tags: oracle, datetime

I need to get the daily schedule for the tasks done by people.

The data in my db is stored like this

```
sno | start_date_time       |  end_date_time      |
---------------------------------------------------
1   |06-10-2016 09:30:00    | 06-10-2016 17:00:00 |
2   |12-10-2016 08:00:00    | 15-10-2016 13:00:00 |
```

My question is if i give a date for  example `14-10-2016` I would like to get the second record.

I dont know how to query it since the given date does not fall into `start_date_time` or `end_date_time`

Is it possible to do that in oracle?

Comment: What do you mean by comparing a date (with no time-of-day component) to date-times? What if the input is 12-10-2016, does that fall within the second row range? (If so, WHY? If not, WHY NOT?)

Answer (score 0):

Try [between](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions011.htm#SQLRF52147)

```
select * from your_table
    where your_date between start_date_time and end_date_time
```

Example:

```
select * from (
    select '2016-01-05' as t1, '2016-02-05' as t2
    union all
    select '2016-05-05' as t1, '2016-08-05' as t2
  ) a
  where '2016-02-01' between t1 and t2
```

gives

```
t1          t2
2016-01-05  2016-02-05
```

Of course this also works not only for dates but also for timestamps.

Keep in mind that when comparing dates and timestamp the date is casted as a 
timestamp like this '2016-01-01' -> '2016-01-01 00:00:00'

Answer (score 0):

Usually start and end dates allow null values, so apart from `between` in PhillipsD answer you might also need `nvl`:

```
select * from your_table
where your_date between nvl(start_date_time, your_date) and nvl(end_date_time, your_date)
```